# Laravel put and get from Session not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in simple controller i want to put and get simple variables to session. in this my code after return to view and callback to other function my session is empty and return null

```
public function doAction()
{
    $this->order_id = Session::get('order_id');
    $this->reference_id = Session::get('reference_id');
    dd(Session::get('order_id') . '  ' . Session::get('reference_id'));
}

public function action(Request $request)
{
    Session::put('order_id', $request->input('order_id'));
    Session::put('reference_id', $request->input('reference_id'));
}
```

My Route:

```
$app->get('paymentRequest', 'PaymentTransactionController@action');
$app->get('doAction', 'PaymentTransactionController@doAction');
```

My View:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ $request['order_id'] }}

    <a href="{{ url('doAction') }}">CLICK</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exact urls you run to achieve that? What exact version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek he uses the first url to activate the action method activating the sessions and the second url to get the sessions out. @ mahdipishguy  Personaly I would advice against using `Session::put()` and `Session::get()` have you tried using the `session()` method like written [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session) in the laravel documentation if your using L5.1+

Comment: Just curious to know: why are you using `$app->get(...)` and not `Route::get(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code is not having any problem, It may be the problem of the configuration. Which local server are you using to host Vagrant, WAMP, MAMP, Homestead, or Nginx seperately ? There are few file we may need to check like php.ini and Laravel's config/session.php or maybe some configuration in nginx.Try using \session::save() to save it manually or try using \session::start() first

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what made you use `$app` in your routes file. But `$app` is the *instance* of the `Laravel` Application and not of the `Route`.

I don't see anywhere written [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routings) that you can / may use `$app` in your routes file to access the `url`s.

Kindly update your routes file to the following and it should work as expected:

```
Route::get('paymentRequest', 'PaymentTransactionController@action');
Route::get('doAction', 'PaymentTransactionController@doAction');
```